# What is the best practice for storing a large number of images for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, image, optimization

I'm in the middle of making an app that will end up needing somewhere between 300-500 different images. I don't know if a database is the right way to go about this, or storing them locally. I doubt locally could do it, seeing as the app size would get huge. Would I just download all the files necessary for an event, then unload them when the event is done

TIA!

Comment: As in standard approach ,Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Library/Caches directory. Examples of files you should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map applications.
Refer link https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html
You can delete files manually if they become obsolete for future purpose .

Comment: one more option is there, called App Thinning, take look at this link when ever the resource needs it will download and deleted when it is not needed, and also app size reduced, one more cool functionality of this is you don't need to manage to  download the resources, all will be taken care by the framework, see for on-demand resources link: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html